# General Linear Model applied to binary data

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, categorical-data, categorical-encoding

So here I am studying regression analysis. As an assignment, I have been asked to obtain some binary data, simulate its behavior from some sample of it and apply the resulting general linear model to the whole data in order to know how accurate it is.

The problem is I am not used to such method when applied to categorical (dummy) variables. More precisely, given the model $\textbf{Y} = \textbf{X}\textbf{B} + \textbf{E}$, I am a little bit lost as to the precise procedure to obtain the matrices $\textbf{Y}$ and $\textbf{X}$.

For example, consider that $\text{man} = 0$ and $\text{woman} = 1$, from whence we obtain the emprical matrix from some target population we are interested in
\begin{align*}
   \textbf{Y} =
\left[ {\begin{array}{c}
   \text{man} \\
   \text{woman} \\
   \text{man} \\
   \text{woman} \\
   \text{man} \\
   \text{man} \\
  \end{array} } \right] =
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   1 & 0 \\
   0 & 1 \\
   1 & 0 \\
   0 & 1 \\
   1 & 0 \\
   1 & 0 \\
  \end{array} } \right]
\end{align*}

My question is: how do we proceed from here? Moreover, how do we get $\textbf{X}$? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model is really $\hat Y$=$XB+E$. Notice the hat on top of the y; y hat is your predicted values for Y. Y is the dependent variable; Y is going to be a *continuous* variable if you're doing regression in the general linear model.

You normally know Y, it's data you've collected. Your X matrix (the design matrix) is what you've called Y. X is just your interdependent variables put into a matrix, you know the values already, they are the data you've collected. Each column represents a different variable. If you dummy code a variable, you split it into separate columns of 1's and 0's, one column for each level, so that each level get a different beta estimate. If your model has an intercept, which most models will, then add a column of 1's to the front your X matrix. Otherwise you've correctly made the dummy variables for gender--just remember which column is for which level.

If you don't know what B (beta coefficients/weights) is, then beta is estimated using $(X^T X)^{-1}  X^t Y$

If this is simulated data, and you've got some made up B  vector, you can literally matrix multiply it with your X and add some simulated normally distributed error and get Y hat. Use that to compare to actual Y by subtracting Y and getting the residuals.

If your Y (dependent variable) is *meant* to be a binary variable, you should *not* fit a regression from the general linear model because that will be biased, but fit using a distribution from the  the generalIZED linear model, i.e. logistic regression.

Comment: In the first place, thanks for the answer. But I still have some questions. Once I have the design matrix based on categorical data, how do I get the matrix $\textbf{Y}$ from empirical data? My question is based on the following dataset:

http://users.stat.ufl.edu/~aa/cda/data.html

I know how to get the design matrix, but I am a little bit lost as to how describe the matrix $\textbf{Y}$.

Comment: which dataset from the webpage?

Comment: The least but one: "Election data set of Table 15.5 (1 = Dem, 0 = Rep)". But if you suggest another one, I would be equally grateful.

Comment: yeah, that dataset isn't going to work for regression, I can't even tell what the dependent variable would be! And no matter which column you pick to be Y it's going to be binary which doesn't fit with regression. 14.15 *might* work. It's count data, so it might not be normally distributed. So try the other columns (except the first one) as the design matrix, and Y is the last column "total vote 2000".

Comment: Check a histogram of that Y column though, if it doesn't look normal then probably the assumptions of regression will be violated. (if you only care about the maths then it'll still add up--you are still fitting a regression, it's just that regression won't estimate the distribution correctly)

Comment: Could you suggest another database? Such example doesn't seem to be appropriate for categorical regression.

Comment: Try this webpage http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/wiki/Main/DataSets the diabetes dataset. Height is (roughly) normally distributed. Many of those variables in there could work too, even though they are skewed, pick one that's not too bad--proper normality is hard to come by in the real world. You can throw in whatever you feel like as independent variables. They might not be significant, but you know, it'll fit.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response and references, it was really helpful!

Comment: Dear Huy, I forgot to ask: could you provide me a data base situation in which I could apply the logistic regression?

Comment: Lots of kaggle datsets will have binary data which requires logistic regression. Eg. given these IV's what is the odds of getting a disease (or not--1 for disease, 0 for no). Basically logistic regression requires your dependent variable to be binary.

Comment: Just a note: for a regression the DV doesn't *have* to be normally distributed, you're really saying Y hat--the Y values *given* the x values will be normally distributed. So regression can fit with many skewed datasets anyway. It's just that if it's skewed already then probably y given x will be skewed (not normal). I was being overcautious just to be sure.